# How to change the default Kendo UI font?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using one of the included KendoUI themes, but I'd like to replace the font family. What is the easiest way to override the entire font family used throughout Kendo UI?

Comment: Did you tried to create a stylesheet to overwrite kendo's fonts ?

Comment: I tried, but I guess I'm asking which selector or how to set the default so I don't have to style each and every element.

Comment: Chrome Developer tools are invaluable for this. Just examine the page and see what the source of the font is. You might start by just overriding the <body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can do below

```
$scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function (event, widget) {
      var styleTag = widget.body.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("style")[0];
      styleTag.parentNode.removeChild(styleTag);
      widget.body.style.fontFamily = '<your font name here>';
      widget.body.style.fontSize = '12px';
      widget.body.style.color = '#35384D';
});
```

Make sure the new font you are using exists in Kendo provided fonts, if it doesn't exist, Kendo will use default Arial font.

To use any other third party font, it needs to be included in Kendo header section. <strike>I am struggling to use google font in Kendo at the moment but will update the thread when I get working example.</strike>

Finally I have to do go for ugly solution to use google font, though Kendo demo show much easier way to do it, but those were not working for me

```
angular.element(angular.element('.k-editable-area .k-content')[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("head"))
                .append("<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
```